# i want to visualize myself about bandwidth of internet

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, isp, network-speed

as we know bandwidth is just a way through which data flows.20 Mbps internet means 20 mega bits per second and 40 Mbps means 40 mega bits per second.i guess 20 Mbps means 20 Mb of data is retrieved in 1 second and 40 Mbps means 40 Mb retrieved in one second.is it like we get more data at less time so we have to pay more or what?please visualize me.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-bandwidth-2625809

Answer (score 1):

Turn your kitchen faucet on just a little, and fill up a glass with water.

Now turn it on all the way and fill up another glass.

Which one fills up faster?

Comment: 2nd one fills up faster for sure and bandwidth is also I guess as same as that.but i want to understand about how ISP provide different bandwidth?as bandwidth is just like a width of a road.Is there a different road for 20 Mbps and 40 Mbps bandwidth?

Comment: That is a completely different question, which you should ask separately.  there are several ways to accomplish that.